# CSS: wildcards within css selector

Tags: css

Im trying to target a number of specific disabled textboxes to alter the color of the text. the format of the ID is:

```
id="jc-cr-lmid-Total-1-RangeFr"
```

Where the number changes from 1-5 depending on the amount of textboxes on the screen.

Is there any way to insert a wildcard for the number while keeping the -RangeFr section of the selector?

I have tried:

```
id*=["jc-cr-lmid-Total-*-RangeFr"]:disabled{
  //Change text color
}
```

But this hasn't worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, sort of; you can use attribute-starts-with and attribute-ends-with notation:

```
[id^="jc-cr-lmid-Total-"][id$="-RangeFr"]:disabled{
  //Change text color
}
```

Note, though, that this allows any sequence of characters between the required start and end, as CSS has no concept of regular expression, so it'll match:

- `id="jc-cr-lmid-Total-1-RangeFr"`
- `id="jc-cr-lmid-Total-1000-RangeFr"`
- `id="jc-cr-lmid-Total-anyOtherSequenceOfCharacters-RangeFr"`

In all honesty, you'd be better off simply using a class for this, which would be far more simple and reliable.

References:

- [CSS attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).

Comment: this answer is more appropriate  here.

Comment: I would use a class but its production code and im under strict instruction to make as low an "impact" change as possible. Tested the above, worked, good answer

Comment: Honestly? I think a class-name would be lower impact than leaving a selector in your production site that's inherently, unavoidably, open to accidental misuse.

Comment: Under any other circumstance i would agree, but unfortunately its another case of non technical BA's dictating what the code base should look like. They see adding a class to each item as too many changes to too many files vs one or two extra selectors in an already gigantic css file

Comment: Constraints are unavoidable, despite their occasional silliness and flaws; I would suggest documenting the refusal to allow use of a class, though, as the approach is unusable in older browsers and prone to misuse (accidental or otherwise); if this leads to an insecurity I suspect you, rather than your manager(s), will be blamed.